# Bisection of chord of parabola $y=-a^2x^2+5ax-4$

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

The chord of a parabola $y=-a^2x^2+5ax-4$ touches the curve $y=\frac{1}{1-x}$ and is bisected by that point. Find the value of $a$.

What do this question mean by bisected by that point? Could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

It means that the chord of the parabola is tangent to the curve $y = 1/(1-x)$, and the point of tangency is the midpoint of the chord.